# IPV6 to country

Tags: c#, geolocation, ipv6

There is a simple IP to country database for IP version 6
http://www.ip2location.com/free/ipv6

```
CREATE TABLE `ip2location_ipv6`(
    `ip_from` DOUBLE,
    `ip_to` DOUBLE,
    `ipv6_from` VARCHAR(40),
    `ipv6_to` VARCHAR(40),
    `country_code` CHAR(2),
    `country_name` VARCHAR(64),
    INDEX `idx_ip_from` (`ip_from`),
    INDEX `idx_ip_to` (`ip_to`),
    INDEX `idx_ip_from_to` (`ip_from`, `ip_to`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

sample row value of this db:

```
"42540528726795050063891204319802818560", "42540528806023212578155541913346768895", "2001:200::", "2001:200:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff", "JP", "Japan"
```

Now I want to get country name of an Ip address. this is my SQL:

```
SQL = "SELECT country_code FROM ip2location_ipv6 WHERE " & IPNumber & " BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to"
```

In this sql there is a parameter called IPNumber. In IPV4 I can calculate IPNumber easily.

```
IPV4: a.b.c.d  => IPNumber = a*(256*256*256) + b*(256*256) + C*(256) + d
```

or I can do it

```
IPNumber = (long)(uint)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((int)IPAddress.Parse("IP_address_Version_4").Address);
```

But I dont have any solution for IPV6 in C#. for example It want to find country name of this IP "2001:DB8::dcaf:BAD" in this database

Comment: You did not indicate the make of the database. Some DBMS (such as PostgreSQL) have natively IP addresses - v4 and v6 - for many years.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from binary to standard IPv6 notation:

Use the `IPAddress` class with the [`public IPAddress(byte[] address)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby.aspx).

Pass in the byte array for the IPv6 address in the constructor then use the `.ToString()` method to [print it in standard notation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tostring.aspx).

---

To convert from standard IPv6 notation to binary:

Create a new `IPAddress` object, and use [`IPAddress.TryParse(string standardNotation)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx) to convert from the standard notation string to a binary value.

Comment: The ip_from and ip_to columns in database are double. IPAddress.TryParse(string standardNotation) convert ip to binary. I want to use this value in this query "SELECT country_code FROM ip2location_ipv6 WHERE " & IPNumber & " BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to"

Comment: So get the bytes from the double and pass them in. They can't be double anyway, because double is only 64-bits and an IPv6 address is 128.

Comment: Good point, double has only 15 significant digits.  This database is pretty borken.

Comment: I didn't check the change history, but as of today, the DB row contains DOUBLE for the IPv4 values and VARCHAR(40) for the IPv6 values.  There is example code for C# .NET 4.0 to convert the IPv6 address string into a BigInteger. http://www.ip2location.com/free/ipv6

Answer (score 0):

You can use latest version mysql 5.6 It is already support IPv6 and commands INET6_ATON(), INET6_NTOA().

Your table will be -

```
CREATE TABLE `ip2location_ipv6`(
    `ip_from` int(11) unsigned,
    `ip_to` int(11) unsigned,
    `ipv6_from` varbinary(16),
    `ipv6_to` varbinary(16),
    `country_code` CHAR(2),
    `country_name` VARCHAR(64),
    INDEX `idx_ip_from` (`ip_from`),
    INDEX `idx_ip_to` (`ip_to`),
    INDEX `idx_ip_from_to` (`ip_from`, `ip_to`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```